# ActionBar align center

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a problem with my alignment in the `ActionBar`.

It is centering the Imageview between the icons, but what I want is that it is centering not depend on the buttons but on the whole `ActionBar`. How can I achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/triptracker_logo"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my java class:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
```

Comment: I think your explanation is incomplete

Comment: why not use a simple layout . You are not using any actionbar specific functionality

Comment: if you are not using any specific functionality of the action bar, just include this layout  in your main layout file and hide the action bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I got from your question is that you want the action bar title to be in center independent of the icon.
Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`
I hope it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/triptracker_logo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In this example `TextView` text will be align left not in Center

Comment: ooh sorry
add this to text view   android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` as root layout instead of `LinearLayout`

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for TextView

`android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` for ImageView to set it at the end

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:text="Helo"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/star"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#b19d9d"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_male" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|end"
                android:gravity="right|end"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:text="HELLO WORLD"

                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```